# Why doesn't Perl's strictures complain about an undeclared $a?

Tags: perl, strictures

Why is there no error issued by `strict`:

```
use strict;

$a = $a + 1;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$a and $b are special globals used by `sort`, so they're always defined.  Try it with $c instead and you will get an error.

Comment: Note that this means using $a and $b for other purposes is a really bad idea.  (Using a variable named $c is also bad, but less so and for other reasons.)

Answer (score 6):

Although `strict` does not complain about the special `$a` and `$b` variables, 
[perlcritic](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/bin/perlcritic) will detect their usage:

> Magic variables should be assigned as
>   "local"... (Severity: 4)

Answer (score 5):

`$a` is a special global variable. It doesn't need to be declared. See [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Answer (score 2):

In Perl there are some global variables. Here `$a` and `$b` are used in the [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) function.

I think you might have noticed, like in this statement:

```
sort { $a <=> $b } @array_name ;
```